# Fitch Natural Deduction proof problem

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, proof-theory, natural-deduction, formal-proofs

I have been working on this proof but I feel like I am stuck in a loop in the end and cannot get one step to be logically out of the sub proof. I have the premise $P \lor \lnot P$ and need to prove $(P \to Q) \to ((\lnot P \to Q) → Q)$.

This is what I have as a complete proof but as I mentioned, just the one line is causing me from having a non valid conclusion. I have left it as a REIT after trying many options. Can someone explain where I may be going wrong in my proof and how I can get that one line to work accordingly?
[image: Fitch Problem]

PS. I am doing my Bsc in Computer Science via correspondence and it has been very challenging teaching myself Formal Logic. Any comments and advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: [Here's how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question); in particular, note that we use MathJax here.

Comment: @Shaun I have reformatted the question's math to mathJax but is the image still valid? I am trying to show the entire proof along with the checkmarks in Fitch.

Comment: Yes, I suppose so.

Comment: Assume $(P \to Q)$ **and** $(\lnot P \to Q)$; then apply $\lor$-elim with $P \lor \lnot P$ to derive $Q$ under both sub-proofs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT

The goal of the subproof is $(\neg P \rightarrow Q) \rightarrow Q$, which is a conditional, so try and set it up as another conditional proof, i.e.:

[image]

Comment: This makes a lot more sense than the long winded proof that I tried. In your example, I see you have left lines 4, 5 without rules and it still worked, is this usually allowed or do we always have to put a rule?

Comment: I see that the final goal will only be true if all the rules have been checked - so my question is answered. Thanks for your help, I will continue working with this and complete it.